# Mover figuras con el mouse

Tags: c#, windows-forms, eventos, opengl

Estoy intentando arrastrar con el **mouse** unas figuras que he dibujado en con **OpenGL**, para ello he utilizado este algoritmo:

1. Obtener posición del centro de la figura y coordenadas del ratón (en pantalla) si nos encontramos en la figura y hacemos clic en ella.
2. Mientras estemos haciendo clic y moviendo el ratón seguimos obteniendo las coordenadas del ratón en pantalla.
3. Al soltar el clic, obtener coordenadas finales
4. Obtener la traslación del mouse mediante resta de coordenadas
5. Obtener la posición final del objeto sumando la traslación a la posición inicial del centro de la figura.

El caso es que funciona a medias, puesto que al arrastrar el ratón estando dentro de la figura, esta se traslada mas que el ratón, haciendo que este salga de ella y por lo tanto haciendo que el método del arrastre se detenga.Llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas a esto y no veo que es lo que falla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado explicar mi problema con una imagen de paint, espero que sirva!

Aquí en código:

```
private void GlControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (hits != 0)//Tiene algo debajo
            {
                MXi = e.X; 
                MYi = e.Y;
                Dragging = true;
                ObjectPosX0 = ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cx;
                ObjectPosY0 = ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cy;
            }

            }
```

`ListaFiguras` es una `List` que contiene los parámetros necesarios para dibujar la figura, luego estos parámetros se los paso a un método en el evento `paint`. Arriba estoy accediendo a los datos del centro y guardándolos como posición inicial.

```
    private void GlControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (Dragging == true)
                    {
                        MXf = e.X;
                        MYf = e.Y;

                        //Modificamos los valores del centro
                        if (identificador > 0)
                        {
                            ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cx = ObjectPosX0 + (MXf - MXi);
                            ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cy = ObjectPosY0 + (-(MYf - MYi));
                        }

                    }
                 }
```

---

```
  private void GlControl1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            MXf = e.X;
            MYf = e.Y;
            Dragging = false;
            //Modificamos los valores del centro
            if (identificador > 0)
            {
                ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cx = ObjectPosX0 + (MXf - MXi);
                ListaFiguras[identificador - 1].cy = ObjectPosY0 + (-(MYf - MYi));
            }

        }
```